# Change file association to the file with the same name but different path

Tags: file-association

I made file association to file `path1/example.bat`. After double-click to associated file in windows explorer was opened related batch file. Later I used `open with` in windows context menu to change association to `path2/example.bat`. Problem is, that after double-click in File explorer was `path1/example.bat` opened. I did try also an `.exe` file, with the same result. So problem should not be in my batch. PC restart does not help. There is value in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\...`, but is somehow hashed, I can not see path to batch file. Renaming to `example2.bat` helps, but this is not, what I want. Is this windows issue? Or what did I miss?

Comment: not about programming = not on-topic for SO; I vote to close/move to Super User.

Comment: thanks @underscore_d , I will try

Comment: solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/608149/how-do-i-change-the-default-program-aka-file-assocation-when-the-program-has-m)